# Indefinite articles as adjectives and adverbs [?]

Tags: grammaticality

Many words can be categorized into two or more parts of speech. For example, ‘fall’ is both a verb and a noun. In, ‘He fell to his knees’, it is a verb. But, in ‘A heavy fall of rain’, it is a noun.

The two articles are [a, an] and the. ‘A’ is sometimes classified as a noun in a dictionary. But, in a phrase like ‘kind of a computer’ [here, it means that there is one computer with many similar models] it modifies the noun ‘computer’ and so it can be classified as an adjective since adjectives modify nouns. [compare ‘the computer’]. But, in the phrase, ‘a kind of computer’ [here, it means a machine which is similar to a computer] it modifies the adjective ‘kind’ and so it is an adverb since adverbs modify adjectives.

So, articles can be classified as adverbs and adjectives, too. [?].

Answer (score 1):

Articles are articles. They cannot be classified as anything else, except in cases where the article in question has other meanings in other contexts (like "A" can be an article, a musical key, and more).

But article is a part of speech in English. There is no need to classify an article as anything else. "A", in particular, is an *indefinite article*.

Answer (score 1):

"Kind" in "a kind of computer" is a noun, not an adjective.

*A(n)* is not an adverb and, as far as I know, don't have any adverbial usages.

Whether or not *a(n)* is an adjective, or an article, depends on how you want to define the words "adjective" and "article". *A(n)* has special behavior and special restrictions that are not shared with (other) adjectives. *A(n)* also doesn't behave exactly the same as the "definite article" *the.*

*A(n)* originated as a reduced form of the numeral *one* and I've seen proposals in some linguistic literature that it might still be possible to analyze it synchronically as some special version of *one* (e.g. "[The indefinite article – Indefinite? – Article?](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1224&context=pwpl)", Thomas Leu, 2012).